# A Constructor to replace the default constructor?

Tags: java

I'm working through a past exam for a computer science paper and have become slightly confused on this part here.

The instructions are to write a class book(done), which has two data fields(also done) a constructor which initializes the two values (done as well) and a constructor which replaces the default constructor (no clue what this is about). I've researched it and gone through my lab notes but I can't understand what they're asking.

Here's the code

```
public class Book{
  //here's the two data fields
  int pages;
  String title;

  public Book (int pageNum, String titleString){//here's the constructor to set the values
    pages = pageNum;
    title = titleString;
  }
}
//so where's the other constructor that replaces the default constructor supposed to go?
```

Comment: That constructor replaces the default constructor. The default constructor only exists if there are no other constructors in the class. See the [language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9).

Comment: You should indent your code properly if you expect people to try and read it.

Comment: It is perhaps just poor wording; they may be asking you to define a zero-arg ctor explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

I think following points mean same thing, which you have already done.

1.which has two data fields(also done) a constructor which initializes the two values
2.constructor which replaces the default constructor (no clue what this is about)

By default class has default constructor. like this

```
public Book()
{
}
```

If write some parameterised constructor, then default constructor will be replaced. By seeing through your code , you have already written parameterised constructor.

Answer (score 0):

It seems they want something like this :

```
public Book() {
    this(0, "");
}
```